# add navigation bar, and tab bar to all pages

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

My current state of app is like this:
[Current state of app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJHbw.png)

Navigation bar and tab bar are both images. There are buttons on the tab bar. Now I have the same set of buttons and images all across the app. I am a total noob in iOS. I wish to use some internal functioning like toolbar/navigation bar/tab bar which is provided by xcode itself, instead of using separate images. I want tab bar and navigation bars in all my pages. Is there any way to add these tab bars and navigation bars to all the pages?
I am also using a superclass, to inherit all the common functions.

I use swift.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to embed in your root `view controller` with a`navigation controller`, and that `navigation controller` embed in with a `tab bar controller`.

To "embed in" a `view controller`, just select your root `view controller` on the`storyboard` and select `Editor` -> `Embed in` -> `Navigation Controller`.

To "embed in" your `navigation controller`, just select it on the `storyboard`and select `Editor` -> `Embed in` -> `Tab Bar Controller`

Comment: I did that now. My storyboard looks like this: http://imgur.com/e1WjSVY But I am unable to add any navigation item in "Top Rated" tab, just like there is "favorite" written on the navigation bar of favorites.

Comment: Remove the `navigation controller` and "embed in" with a `navigation controller` every `view controller` so every `view controller` is going to have their own `navigation controller` and then you must can add any navigation item.